# Required Field Validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my aspx page code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName"
     controltovalidate="txtName" 
     errormessage="Please enter your name!" />
```

its not working. i am not getting error message when i click in ok button then it shows error.

Comment: `then it shows error` What's the error ?

Comment: @yogi: I assume the problem is that the validator does not work as expected and the page posts back even if the text is empty. Then the error comes from database.

Comment: Add `ValidationGroup` property in both textbox and required field validator

Comment: @user1512: Why should that help? If you don't specify a ValidationGroup it validates always.

Comment: What have you used to postback? A serverside `Button` control?

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter i want to Validate on client side . when i click tab button and textbox is emplt is it possible ?

Comment: I cannot see `TabButton` on your aspx code, have you forgotten to add it? By default ASP.NET validates also on clientside.

Comment: tab button means click tab on keyboard

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter 
are u getting my Question ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19370/discussion-between-rohan-panchal-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using jquery, you can use the `blur` event as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName"
     controltovalidate="txtName" 
     errormessage="Please enter your name!" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= txtName.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
        var control = document.getElementById('<%= reqName.ClientID %>');
        ValidatorEnable(control);
        ValidatorValidate(control);
        ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i dont want to validate on button click i want to validate when i click tab button and text box is Empty

Comment: @rohanpanchal What kind of control is of your tab button?

Comment: Tab button is in our Keyborad.

Comment: @rohanpanchal how was anyone supposed to know you wanted this behavior on blur? see update for how to validate a control manually.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared much code but most probably you could do one thing to make things work do this.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqName" 
         ControlToValidate="txtName"
         ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!" 
         ValidationGroup="save" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button" 
         Text="Click me" 
         ValidationGroup="save" />
```

Give a `ValidationGroup` to your `RequiredFieldValidator` and `Button` (could be other postback causing control like `ImageButton` etc. too).

**UPDATE**

If you want to validate on TAB too do this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqName" 
         ControlToValidate="txtName"
         ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!" 
         ValidationGroup="save" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button" 
         Text="Click me" 
         ValidationGroup="save" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fireValid() {
        if (Page_ClientValidate('save')) // save is your validation group here
        {
            //Your valid
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I just assume that he could have multiple postback causing controls in his form like save and cancel, then we should specify this property.

Comment: it shows error message ** Please enter your name! ** i want same messge when i click tab and textbox is empty